# How to do this in Laravel subquery

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, subquery

I have two tables: Receipts (id, name, advice...) and Ingradients (id_ingradient, id_receipt, ingradient, type_measuring ...).
How can I select data in next order

```
[{
  'id': 5,
  'name': 'fried potatoes',
  'advice': '...',

  'ingradients': [{
    'id_ingradient': 1,
    'id_receipt': 5,
    'ingradient': 'potato',
    'type_measuring': 'gram'
  },
  {
    'id_ingradient': 2,
    'id_receipt': 5,
    'ingradient': 'water',
    'type_measuring': 'ml'
  }]
}]
```

I need to do this query in Laravel

Comment: What do you mean by "next order"?

Comment: @Dula my select should to give info in same order. Can i do it?

Comment: and can you show us the query you tried that give you info in same order?

Comment: As @anon mentioned, can you show us the query you used?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.